# How to subscribe to UPnP events

Tags: c#, http-headers, httprequest, upnp

This should really be a simple `HttpRequestMessage` question for most. I'm trying to send a subscription request to a UPnP device as described in section 4.1.2 of the [UPnP Device Architecture doc](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf) and the message I need to send is supposed to look like the following:

```
SUBSCRIBE publisher path HTTP/1.1
HOST: publisher host:publisher port  
USER-AGENT: OS/version UPnP/1.1 product/version  
CALLBACK: <delivery URL>  
NT: upnp:event  
TIMEOUT: Second-requested subscription duration
```

obviously most of this is pretty straight forward. There are a few items I have questions on because my current method does not work. I get a `NotFound` returned from the server.

Is the *request line* **SUBSCRIBE publisher path HTTP/1.1** the same as when I create the WebRequest (`WebRequest.Create(...)`) or is there property somewhere I can set?

Is `SUBSCRIBE` the `HttpMethod` in this case or is this a `Get`, `POST`, `PUT` etc?

Here's the current request code:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(eventUri)) as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "SUBSCRIBE";
request.UserAgent = "MyTab/1.0 UPnP/1.1 TestApp/1.0";
request.Headers["CALLBACK"] = "<" + hostname.DisplayName + ":8088>";
request.Headers["NT"] = "upnp:event";
request.Headers["TIMEOUT"] = "Second-300";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like I had it all correct, except I forgot to append the `http://` to the callback url.

Answer (score 2):

For others who land here and wonder how UPNP Subscriptions work. This is a very simplified usage example.

I'll use netcat to open a port and respond to incoming events with an HTTP 200. To initialize the connection I'll use curl. This works on an Ubuntu 19.10 with preinstalled curl and nc.

```sh
curl -v http://192.168.1.47:58424/RenderingControl/evt -H "CALLBACK: <http://192.168.1.32:1234>" -H "NT: upnp:event" -H "TIMEOUT: Second-1800" -X SUBSCRIBE
```

Here `http://192.168.1.47:58424/RenderingControl/evt` is the device specific URL to register to the event. The `CALLBACK` header specifies the port and IP address on which our netcat server is running. It is important here to add `http://` as mentioned before.

The server that listens and sends the HTTP OK is run with the following:

```sh
while true; do echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' | nc -l 1234; done
```